# DetailView is missing a QuerySet Error. shouldnt it work with the primary key?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, detailview, django-class-based-views

Quite new to this super nice django thing. Trying my best...

trying http://127.0.0.1:8000/angebot/1/ in my browser
is supposed to show me the queryset with the primary key 1 from model Testkunde

do i need to define a queryset in the detailview ??
normally with
model = Testkunde
this should be done ??

would really appreciate any help !
thanks in advance!

**views.py**

```
class TestkundeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Testkunde
    template_name = 'angebot/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'testkunde_list'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', angebot_views.testkunde_list, name='testkunde_list'),
    path('', angebot_views.TestkundeListView.as_view(), name='angebot-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', angebot_views.DetailView.as_view(), name='angebot-detail'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Testkunde(models.Model):
    auswahl = (
        ('Ausw1', 'Ausw2'),
        ('Ausw2', 'ausw2'),
        ('Ausw3', 'ausw3'),
    )

    vname = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='vname')
    nname = models.TextField(default='default')
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='0664')
    ausw = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=auswahl,default="Ausw1")
    datum = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vname

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('angebot:testkunde_list',)
```

Error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /angebot/1/
> DetailView is missing a QuerySet. Define DetailView.model, DetailView.queryset, or override DetailView.get_queryset().
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/angebot/1/
> Django Version: 3.0.8
> Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
> Exception Value:
> DetailView is missing a QuerySet. Define DetailView.model, DetailView.queryset, or override DetailView.get_queryset().
> Exception Location: C:\Users\berni\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py in get_queryset, line 73
> Python Executable:  C:\Users\berni\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.7.7
> Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\berni\PycharmProjects\django_project\django_project',
> 'C:\Users\berni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
> 'C:\Users\berni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\berni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
> 'C:\Users\berni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
> 'C:\Users\berni\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv',
> 'C:\Users\berni\PycharmProjects\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages']
> Server time:    Fri, 27 Nov 2020 08:19:51 +0000

I've been searching but can't find the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see, the problem is in your URLs pattern. Your URL for the **angebot-detail** is pointing to the actual `DetailView` rather than your `TestkundeDetailView` that you defined in your views.py file.

You should update your **angebot-detail** url to the following:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:pk>/', angebot_views.TestkundeDetailView.as_view(), name='angebot-detail'),
]
```

Don't forget to import your `TestkundeDetailView` at the top.

Comment: Sebastian, thanks a lot. This solved my problem.
This is a big problem for me... maybe also for others ??
Just a small typo/mistake is ruining everything.
I think i need to learn how to debug this django thing properly...